# How to find a set of specific folders and delete their content recursively starting from a path

Tags: windows-server-2003

I would like to delete all folders whose name is for instance 'toDelete', starting from a specific path on Windows server 2003, with a console script. 
Moreover I would like to exclude the search in some folder.
Is it possible?